# rails ssl localhost no respond when http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, localhost, webrick

I want running rails server on localhost:9292 and that's work fine when access with http:// . but, when I access with https:// that's always result this error :

> Certificate:
>       Data:
>           Version: 1 (0x0)
>           Serial Number:
>               e8:ca:87:ac:95:da:40:6e
>       Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>           Issuer: C=ID, ST=java, L=bandung, O=gramediana, OU=gramediana, CN=gramediana/emailAddress=ihsan.husnul@kiranatama.com
>           Validity
>               Not Before: Feb  4 08:14:20 2013 GMT
>               Not After : Feb  4 08:14:20 2014 GMT
>           Subject: C=ID, ST=java, L=bandung, O=gramediana, OU=gramediana, CN=gramediana/emailAddress=ihsan.husnul@kiranatama.com
>           Subject Public Key Info:
>               Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>                   Public-Key: (1024 bit)
>                   Modulus:
>                       00:e2:40:95:b2:99:b6:88:2e:f2:bb:a5:f3:73:6b:
>                       b4:4d:f4:93:ea:8a:3e:b6:cb:f1:31:b5:8b:44:79:
>                       18:e4:20:9e:19:d1:3d:fa:6e:ba:d4:09:a5:02:07:
>                       f0:c1:ab:ff:13:af:50:d4:59:f3:0d:ea:d4:0a:d6:
>                       8c:40:b7:e7:01:7b:c5:c9:f3:4f:72:76:60:8e:59:
>                       49:d1:ab:9d:74:38:d2:0e:61:88:64:a7:a8:1e:2d:
>                       2d:8e:b1:c4:f6:48:48:8f:b2:22:8f:1f:4f:39:18:
>                       b5:04:db:fb:3e:a7:8a:15:7f:e9:0c:35:f1:7c:79:
>                       36:81:33:16:66:00:35:f5:57
>                   Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
>       Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>            ad:cd:64:b3:6d:a2:fb:b7:97:8a:05:54:38:f1:12:83:2a:5b:
>            bc:42:82:2c:95:bf:90:5e:22:ee:8f:29:a1:34:39:d3:f1:3d:
>            b9:8b:6f:86:39:b3:6e:85:32:04:d1:9c:b0:5b:ff:fc:76:73:
>            3c:09:4c:9a:67:83:53:a7:14:c9:40:10:8e:e9:35:57:4e:e1:
>            52:28:07:39:6f:da:6a:d6:17:5e:26:4c:37:1b:bc:f3:97:a0:
>            a4:13:64:9d:02:38:7b:02:12:50:a9:89:80:eb:19:74:b9:60:
>            5b:17:d8:94:25:ea:e3:80:e3:21:43:13:a1:98:72:a2:0c:34:
>            93:cc [2013-02-04 15:29:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11446 port=9292 [2013-02-04 15:29:14] ERROR
>   OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown
>   state: http request
>     /home/ihsan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:164:in
>   `accept' [2013-02-04 15:29:15] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
>   SSL_accept returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: http request
>     /home/ihsan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:164:in`
>   accept' [2013-02-04 15:29:15] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
>   SSL_accept returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: http request
>     /home/ihsan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:164:in
>   `accept' [2013-02-04 15:29:25] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
>   SSL_accept SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
>     /home/ihsan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:164:in`
>   accept'

I'm very stack in these case. somebody help me. :(